# Route53 pointing to cloudfront www

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have seen a lot of tutorials about having non-www domain hosting of S3 static websites but I've yet to see one which works on www domains, i.e www.jobkent.com.

My steps so far is to create a bucket called www.jobkent.com
Then I set the bucket as a static website host with index.html as the base

1. When creating a hosted zone, should the domain name be www.jobkent.com or jobkent.com?
2. How to I point the www. to my S3 website like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a hosted zone on route53, as on all dns servers/services, is a top level domain.  in your case, with route53, the TLD is "hosted" by amazon.

the way to make www.tld.com go to your s3 bucket is to add a dns CNAME record for "www" pointing to the s3 bucket FQDN (fully qualified domain name).

for example, this would look like

> www.tld.com. 3600 IN CNAME your_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com.

or, thru the route53 gui, enter "www" in the textbox at top, select CNAME from dropdown, and put "your_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com." in the text field below the drop down selector.